# directing problem with struct , can you help me?

Tags: c, windows, struct, syntax-error, temp

I'm a beginner programmer, and I have to solve this homework, but I have a problem.
When I use this program, the system write out this problem:

```
Syntax Error(s)
__tester__.c: In function ‘main’:
__tester__.c:64:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct jatekok’ from type ‘float’
 csere = tarsas[i].ertekeles;
       ^
__tester__.c:66:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float’ from type ‘struct jatekok’
 tarsas[j].ertekeles=csere;
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct jatekok{
  char nev[50];
  int ev;
  float ertekeles;
  int min;
  int max;
  
}csere;


int main()
{
    struct jatekok tarsas[8];
    
     for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s %d %f %d %d", tarsas[i].nev, &tarsas[i].ev, &tarsas[i].ertekeles, &tarsas[i].min, &tarsas[i].max);
        
    }
    
    printf("A beolvasott adatok:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
       printf("%s (%d): ertekeles: %.1f, jatekosok szama: %d-%d\n", tarsas[i].nev, tarsas[i].ev, tarsas[i].ertekeles, tarsas[i].min, tarsas[i].max); 
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("Az 5 fovel jatszhato jatekok:\n");
    
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if(tarsas[i].max>=5)
        {
            printf("%s\n", tarsas[i].nev);
            
        }
        
    }
    
    int regi=2040;
    int index =0;
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if(tarsas[i].ev<regi)
        {
            regi=tarsas[i].ev;
            index=i;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("A legregebbi jatek: ");
    printf("%s\n", tarsas[index].nev);
    
     printf("\n");
    printf("A rendezett jateklista:\n");
    
   struct jatekok csere;
   for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
for(int j=i+1;j<8;j++)
if(tarsas[i].ertekeles<tarsas[j].ertekeles)
{
csere = tarsas[i].ertekeles;
tarsas[i].ertekeles=tarsas[j].ertekeles;
tarsas[j].ertekeles=csere;
}

for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
       printf("%s (%d): ertekeles: %.1f, jatekosok szama: %d-%d\n", tarsas[i].nev, tarsas[i].ev, tarsas[i].ertekeles, tarsas[i].min, tarsas[i].max); 
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

But if I use this, the program is correct, and I don't understand what's the difference between those. Can you help me? The programs are written in c.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct jatek{
    char nev[50];
    int ev;
    float ertekeles;
    int minjatekos;
    int maxjatekos;
};
int main(){
    struct jatek Jatekok[8];
    printf("A beolvasott adatok:\n");
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
        scanf("%s %d %f %d %d",Jatekok[i].nev,&Jatekok[i].ev,&Jatekok[i].ertekeles, &Jatekok[i].minjatekos, &Jatekok[i].maxjatekos);
        printf("%s (%d): ertekeles: %.1f, jatekosok szama: %d-%d\n",Jatekok[i].nev,Jatekok[i].ev,Jatekok[i].ertekeles, Jatekok[i].minjatekos, Jatekok[i].maxjatekos);};

    printf("\nAz 5 fovel jatszhato jatekok:\n");

    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
        if (Jatekok[i].maxjatekos>=5 && Jatekok[i].minjatekos <=5)
            printf("%s\n",Jatekok[i].nev);

    int minev = Jatekok[0].ev;
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
        if (Jatekok[i].ev<= minev)
        minev = Jatekok[i].ev;
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
        if (Jatekok[i].ev == minev){
            printf("\nA legregebbi jatek: %s\n\nA rendezett jateklista:\n",Jatekok[i].nev);
            break;};

    struct jatek temp;
    for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
        for (int j=i+1;j<8;j++)
            if (Jatekok[i].ertekeles < Jatekok[j].ertekeles){
                temp = Jatekok[i];
                Jatekok[i] = Jatekok[j];
                Jatekok[j] = temp;};
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf("%s (%d): ertekeles: %.1f, jatekosok szama: %d-%d\n",Jatekok[i].nev,Jatekok[i].ev,Jatekok[i].ertekeles, Jatekok[i].minjatekos, Jatekok[i].maxjatekos);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about what compiler says;

You have an apple in your right hand and a pizza in your left hand. Is these two things are identical ? No, it is not. But you are act like that these are identical.

```
csere = tarsas[i].ertekeles;
tarsas[i].ertekeles=tarsas[j].ertekeles;
tarsas[j].ertekeles=csere;
```

`csere` is a struct type, but you are assign float variable. No, pizza and apple are not identical. And then you are trying to assign different types each other like `tarsas[j].ertekeles=csere`

**Correct Version**

```
csere = tarsas[i];
tarsas[i].ertekeles=tarsas[j].ertekeles;
tarsas[j] = csere;
```

If we look at the same part of the other's code

```
temp = Jatekok[i];
Jatekok[i] = Jatekok[j];
Jatekok[j] = temp;
```

`temp` is a struct and Jatekok[i] is an another struct.

Comment: now, I tried with temp. but it sill not working

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

struct jatekok{
  char nev[50];
  int ev;
  float ertekeles;
  int min;
  int max;  
};

    
int main()
{
    
   struct jatekok temp;
   for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
{
for(int j=i+1;j<8;j++)
{
if(tarsas[i].ertekeles<tarsas[j].ertekeles)
{
temp = tarsas[i].ertekeles;
tarsas[i].ertekeles=tarsas[j].ertekeles;
tarsas[j].ertekeles=temp;
}
}
}

for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
       printf("%s (%d): ertekeles: %.1f, jatekosok szama: %d-%d\n", tarsas[i].nev, tarsas[i].ev, tarsas[i].ertekeles, tarsas[i].min, tarsas[i].max); 
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}

Comment: sorry, if its an easy thing , but dont understand

Comment: the problem is still the same. now it write this: Syntax Error(s)
__tester__.c: In function ‘main’:
__tester__.c:66:6: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct jatekok’ from type ‘float’
 temp = tarsas[i].ertekeles;
      ^
__tester__.c:68:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float’ from type ‘struct jatekok’
 tarsas[j].ertekeles=temp;

Comment: I have just edited my answer and added correct assignment syntax.

Comment: ohh Jesus, im an idiot, we had to switch the all tarsas[i], and not just the tarsas[i].ertekeles. Thank you so much

Comment: Please dont forget the approve my answer with clicking the green button.

Comment: I tried that at the first answer already, but i have not enough reputattion for this, sorry for i cant give back the favour:(